# How to add gradient background

Tags: css, linear-gradients

As the title says I am trying to add a gradient background to the one page on my website. I am currently doing this in CSS:

```
body {
  background: rgb(85,205,252);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(85,205,252,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 35%, rgba(247,168,184,1) 100%);
}
```

But doing it this way makes the gradient jagged and not very smooth.

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnya7bqv/)

It should be looking like this
[image: Screenshot of page with proper background]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the gradient is repeating over and over. It is doing this as it is the same size as `<body>`, which is actually very small as there is only that one `.intro` element taking up space within it.

You can fix this by stopping the background from repeating, and making the body the full height of the window at minimum, like so:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Edit: technically the 'no-repeat' is redundant when using a gradient background, as it will always fill the height provided the height is at or above 100vh.

However I would leave it there anyway as good practice just in case the background ever changes to an image; or for edge cases where the min-height may get overridden.